# Count distinct in SAP HANA graphical calculation view

Tags: hana, hana-studio

We have below table as -

| CUSTOMER_NO | ORDER_NO | ITEM_NO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | O1 | I1 |
| C1 | O1 | I2 |
| C1 | O1 | I3 |
| C1 | O2 | I4 |
| C1 | O2 | I2 |

What I need is count of distinct orders and count of ITEMS per customer -

| CUSTOMER_NO | ORDER_NO | ITEM_NO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 2 (distinct) | 5 (not distinct) |

How can this be achieved in SAP HANA graphical calculation view?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a counter for that in the graphical calc view.
This is explained at length in the modelling guide - I recommend to give that document a read. [Using Calculation Views](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/fc5ace7a367c434190a8047881f92ed8/d60ad1f0bb571014af49c9db1740d68c.html?locale=en-US) could be an entry point for reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Please check followins SQL Select statement,

```
select 
    distinct
    t1.CUSTOMER_NO, 
    (select count(distinct t2.ORDER_NO) from OrderItems t2 where t2.CUSTOMER_NO = t1.CUSTOMER_NO) as ORDER_NO,
    (select count(distinct t2.ITEM_NO) from OrderItems t2 where t2.CUSTOMER_NO = t1.CUSTOMER_NO) as ITEM_NO
from OrderItems t1
```

There is an easier way if we could apply the [COUNT aggregate function with Partition By](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx) clause in SAP HANA as we do in SQL Server. As I see HANA SQLScript developers cannot use this syntax right now for Count() function
So I used sub-selects as seen in above SELECT code

I hope it helps,